# Should I use windbg_x86 for debugging 32bit applications in 64bit windows?

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg, x86-64, remote-debugging

I use windows 7 x64 with intel cpu. which windbg works fine and should I use for debugging x86 apps ?
and another similar question, I install windows XP x86 as vmware guest for kernel debugging.My host is x64 windows 7.which windbg should I use?, windbg x86 or x64 for kernel debugging ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to say RTFM, but in this case that's where the answer is.
This is an extract from WinDbg help:

> **Host computer running a 32-bit version of Windows**
>   If your host computer is running a 32-bit version of Windows, use the 32-bit debugging tools. (This situation applies to both x86-based and x64-based targets.)
>
> **x64-based host computer running a 64-bit version of Windows**
>   If your host computer uses an x64-based processor and is running a 64-bit version of Windows, the following rules apply:
>
> - If you are analyzing a dump file, you can use either the 32-bit debugging tools or the 64-bit debugging tools. (It is not important whether the dump file is a user-mode dump file or a kernel-mode dump file, and it is not important whether the dump file was made on an x86-based or an x64-based platform.)
> - If you are performing live kernel-mode debugging, you can use either the 32-bit debugging tools or the x64 debugging tools. (This situation applies to both x86-based and x64-based targets.)
> - If you are debugging live user-mode code that is running on the same computer as the debugger, use the 64-bit tools for debugging 64-bit code and 32-bit code running on WOW64. To set the debugger for 32-bit or 64-bit mode, use the .effmach command.
> - If you are debugging live 32-bit user-mode code that is running on a separate target computer, use the 32-bit debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually best to match the debugger to the architecture of the application being debugged (sometimes even required).  For debugging 32-bit applications, even on a 64-bit windows OS I would suggest the x86 version of WinDbg.  I would use the x64 version of WinDbg only if I wanted to debug part of the WOW64 part of the 32-bit application, which shouldn't happen often.

Comment: The part of this answer dealing with user mode is correct, x86 version for debugging x86 applications and x64 for debugging x64 application. However, when it comes to kernel debugging, the version on the target does not matter at all. You can use either version (x86/x64) to debug either target type (x86/x64). Same goes for kernel memory dumps.

Comment: @snoone thanks, didn't know that.  Removed that part of the answer.